# Blurring box-shadow with the blur filter causes strange lines in Webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently, I came across an interesting and annoying bug in WebKit browsers.

Take the case of having a parent DIV (in this case, we'll use `.wrapper`) and a child DIV (`.main`) for example. Apply a box-shadow on the `.main` DIV and a blur filter on the `.wrapper` DIV. Like so:

```
.wrapper {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
       -moz-filter: blur(3px);
            filter: blur(3px);
}

.main {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Run it, and you'll notice a grid pattern in the `.main` DIV. Strangely enough, this only occurs when there is no background on the `.main` DIV and when the `.main` DIV has a box-shadow applied to it. [Here's a live demo of what I'm referring to](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpWBJz).

Now my question is, without adding a background to the `.main` DIV, is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening? I've tried using a drop-shadow filter but it doesn't give me the features that I need like box-shadow does. Or am I gonna have to wait for this to be patched in WebKit?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following rule to `.main` [seems to](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNbQJy) resolve problems in Webkit `transform: translateZ(0);`

It shouldn't actually do anything but workaround the bug.

Comment: That's very strange... Maybe it has to do with the fact that adding that rule causes the DIV to be GPU accelerated? Whatever it is, it solved my problem! Thank you!